# Symfony + Doctrine - Set property default value equal to ID

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine

I have a `Question` entity with a property called `code`. I want to set the value of `code` equal to `id` on default with Doctrine annotations.

This is how I tried but I'm getting an error:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id; 

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $code = $id;
```

Or:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id; 

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options = {"default": $id})
 */
private $code;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of duplicate the id ?

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

I don't know what is your need but maybe postPersist event is what you want :

> postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the
>   entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database
>   insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the
>   postPersist event.

Then in your entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id; 

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $code;

/** @PostPersist */
public function doStuffOnPostPersist()
{
    $this->code = $this->id;
}
```

It is important to understand that your doctrine entity will have an ID only after having been persisted, thus after the post persist event.